# Finding specific columns across whole DB and update all Record

Tags: sql

I'm really new to SQl (sorry) and have been having a look at our internal database, we have a problem where a user-account has been created with a space at the front (this was done several years ago). This is causing numerous errors when viewing data on records where this account has been used in our front end application.

The slight issue is the database developer left years ago and nobody has mapped this DB.

Is there a query which can be run that would allow us to locate all instances of this user_id value across the whole database schema (and a log schema) and then one to update all the records to remove the space?

Thank you

Comment: First question, is this MSSQL, MySQL or something else?

Comment: Sorry, my bad it's PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

If you know  the exact column name then  possibly, you can get the list of tables which consists the column.

select  TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where COLUMN_NAME like  'Column name'

It is not possible to update the column values  of all the tables at a time. Update each table column separately.
You may have the Userid.  Use the below Query to update.

Update  Table Name
Set columnname= Ltrim(UserID)
where columnname like '%UserID%'